# How can I translate in lyx?

Tags: lyx, overleaf, lyx-layouts, tex2lyx

thank you all.
I can translate from language to another **manually**.
Are there any way to  translate a lyx document, for example, from English to Arabic in the same way as in a Word document such that the mathematical expressions remain as they were?
I want do this automatically by a lyx function if possible.

Comment: Translation is no more TeX's job than spelling correction, grammar or auto-formatting. I have no idea what LyX does. Why have you tagged this Overleaf?

Comment: Besides that you could find marginally useful some of the LaTeX packages for [multilingual support](https://ctan.org/topic/multilingual), the short answer is no.

Comment: A good question for the Lyx developer team ...